# CakePHP SQL conversion - basic ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, find

I have a table where I'd like to get all id's that equal 26 first, then have the rest sorted in descending order, so something like:

```
row    id
---    --

1      26
2      26
3      26
4      27
5      25
6      24
```

Would normally result in:

```
select id 
from table 
order by id=26 desc, id desc
```

How should I construct a `find()` in Cake? This is what I figure:

```
$this->Model->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('Model.id' => 26),
    'order' => array('Model.id' => 'DESC')
));
```

But how should I tell Cake to retrieve the rest of the id's and sort them in descending order after retrieving all id's that equal 26?

Comment: `array('Model.id' DESC)` is not valid PHP. Your IDE should tell you that.

Comment: just edited, forgot to pair them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
$this->Model->find('all', array(
  'order' => array('Model.id = 26 DESC' , 'Model.id DESC')
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `id` field is your primaryKey as defined by the CakePHP conventions, the query you have will only ever return one result. Thus the ordering is not relevant here.

I would also suggest using `find('first')` to prevent you getting a single result indexed numerically.

`$this->Model->find('first', array('conditions' => array('id' => $id)));`

If you wanted to return this single record, and then all the other records, I would inverse this with a `find('all')`.

`$this->Model->find('all', array('conditions' => array('id !=' => $id)));`